# how to avoid duplicate options from dropdown array in jquery

Tags: jquery

On each buttonClick, I am creating a new dropdown list where the options are populated dynamically. Since dropdown list is populated dynamically I get duplicate options appended to dropdown.As dropdown name is an array each time a new dropdown is created using button click, the same options are added duplicate to already existing dropdown. How to avoid this duplicate option to be appended.
Here is My html Code

```
<Select name=test[]>
  <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="a">Test Value1</option>
</select>

<Select name=test[]>
  <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="a">Test Value2</option>
</select>

<Select name=test[]>
  <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="a">Test Value3</option>
</select>

$.each(data, function(index, testcd) {
    $("select[name*='test']").append(new Option(testcd.TestName,testcd.Testid));

                        });
```

Since the name of the select is same, when a new dropdown is added during button click the options for first dropdown is added twice. How to avoid adding option duplicate in case of select array

Comment: You should have some unique thing to identify each dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

When you build your dropdown, give a unique Id to your dropdown and whenever you hae to load data to it, use this unique id for your jQuery selector.

```
<Select id="dropddown1" name="test[]">
  <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="a">Test Value1</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$.each(data, function(index, testcd) {
    $("#dropddown1").append(new Option(testcd.TestName,testcd.Testid));
});
```

Or if you are building the dropdown and loading data to it, You may use the jQuery object of the created dropdown and just add data to that only.

```
$(function(){

  $("#create").click(function(e){

    var d=$("<select name='test'><select>");       
    $("body").append(d);  
    // d id the jQuery object for the new dropdown
    loadDataToDropDown(d);      
  });      

});

function loadDataToDropDown(d)
{
  var items= [{TestName:"First",Testid:123},
         {TestName:"Second",Testid:123}];
  //items could be data coming from an ajax call
  $.each(items,function(a,item){
     d.append("<option value='"+item.Testid+"'>"+item.TestName+"</option>");
  });

}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/copebi/edit?html,js,output) is a sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear all the option first to prevent duplicate issue. Update your code to :

```
$("select[name*='test']")
    .empty()
    .append(new Option(testcd.TestName,testcd.Testid));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution.

You just need to add or modify class in below example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).find('select').change(function () {
        if ($(document).find('select option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]:selected').length > 1) {
          $(this).val('').change();
          alert('Already selected values')
        }
      });
    });
```